# Pandas dataframe groupby sum strings in reverse order

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have a DataFrame like this:

```
colA    colB 
1       aaa
1       rrr
1       www
2       bbb
2       ccc
2       sss
...
```

I would like to convert the DataFrame as follows

```
colA    Sum
1       wwwrrraaa
2       ssscccbbb
...
```

I tried

```
df.groupby(['colA'])['colB'].sum().reset_index()
```

but the sum of strings are reversed. Is there an elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use sum to concatenate strings. It looks fancy but it's quadratic and should be considered bad practice. In python is use function `join`

```
df = df[::-1].groupby('colA')['colB'].agg(''.join).reset_index()
```

Answer (score 2):

Reverse the DataFrame; then `groupby` + `sum`:

```
out = df[::-1].groupby('colA', as_index=False)['colB'].sum()
```

Output:

```
   colA       colB
0     1  wwwrrraaa
1     2  ssscccbbb
```